# How to make a program that automatically runs a program for many input files?

Tags: build-automation

Sorry if my title didn't make much sense, but here is what I need:

So I am running an open source ocr program tesseract and I use it in command prompt (I use windows), such that 'tesseract input.jgp output.txt'  This command would take the input.jpg
and convert it into output.txt

I have hundreds of input files that I have to convert.(or even more) Is there any way I could
make a program so that it would automatically run the tesseract program for different input files???

I am really sorry if my description isn't enough, and if that's the case, please tell me whatelse I should describe.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the windows cmd shell, change to the folder containing the jpg files and try

```
 for %i in (*.jpg) do tesseract %i %~ni.txt
```

This runs tesseract for each jpg file and places the output in a text file with similar name, but suffix "txt" instead of jpg. To learn more about the "for" command, type "help for" on the command line. If you need a tutorial on cmd shell programming, try this one: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/win32/win32scripting.html#Win32Scripting-Control-Constructs

Comment: Thank you so much!! it did work! now I just gotta make a batch file with the code!

Comment: @Sardonic: did you not follow my advice to type "help for" at the command line? On the third help page is a complete list of those `%~?i` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your input files in a single folder? You can create a Batch file to iterate over all the jpg files in the folder and run your tesseract program on those files.

If you want to program the "iterator" program in a certain language, see if that language has a way to call a Windows program. Most languages have at least 1 way to do this.

FYI, if your input files aren't in a single folder, you'll have to have a way to specify the locations of all the images in the "iterator" program. How you do that is based on how your input files are spread out.

Comment: yes, all of my input files will be in a single folder. Would you give me any tip on how to make such a batch file?? I have no previous experience in making batch files,,, this is my very first time working on side project besides class projects, so I am having trouble making basic programs. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

[VietOCR](http://vietocr.sf.net), a GUI frontend for Tesseract, provides support for bulk ocr functionality.